# Function declaration in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If we write

```
mase_me= new Function('','return \'aaa\';');
alert(mase_me.toString());
```

then displays `function anonymous() { return 'aaa'; }`. Further i'm trying to call function, I'm write

```
alert(anonymous());
```

but i have an error

```
[18:23:40.220] ReferenceError: anonymous is not defined @ http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:33
```

I'm excepted that `alert(anonymous());` will display `aaa` because if I write

```
made_me=function aaa() { return 'aaa'; }
alert(made_me.toString());
```

then will display `function aaa(){ return 'aaa'}` and

```
alert(aaa());
```

will display `aaa`.

Comment: anonymous means "unnamed" ... Javascript tells you that the function doesn't have a name. So you cannot just use `anonymous` as if it was the name of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`anonymous` is the name of the function, not the name of the variable containing a reference to the function — that is `mase_me`.

You can see that because `new Function('','return \'aaa\';').name === "anonymous"`.

---

When you do:

```
function aaa() { return 'aaa'; }
```

It is *effectively* the same as:

```
var aaa = function aaa() { return 'aaa'; }
```

(**note** that is is not exactly the same: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname))

---

Naturally, this works the same with functions created in such a way that have been given an explicit name:

```
var a = new Function("b", "return 'aaa';");
a(); // works
b(); // doens't work (not defined)
a.name === "b" // true
```

Comment: That's interesting, must be a Moz-only thing. In Chrome, `new Function().name` and `(function(){}).name` are both an empty string. In Moz, `new Function().name` is "anonymous" but `(function(){}).name` is an empty string. Weird.

Comment: I was actually surprised myself that the name of `new Function()` was equal to `"anonymous"` in Firefox, I was expecting it to be an empty string like `(function(){}).name`! The behaviour in Chrome seems more sensible to me.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you do a `new Function()`, it is called an anonymous function. They are for the purpose of closures. However, you should always us a literal, such as `[]`, `""`, and `function(){}`, instead of `new Function()`.

To call the function, you should do `mase_me()`, not `anonymous()`, since `anonymous` is the name given to any function constructed like that.

Answer (score 1):

`anonymous` is not the function's name. It is simply an indicator that the function has no name, a placehoder if you wish.

While you can't call an anonymous function by name, you can call it by using a reference to it. You have such a reference in the `mase_me` variable:

```
alert(mase_me()) // alerts 'aaa'
```

The only other way to call it is by calling it immediately when it is constructed, but i doubt it would help in your case:

```
alert((new Function('','return \'aaa\';'))());
```